# Can you include multiple labels in the same PDF using shippo.transaction.create({...})

Tags: shippo

I am creating a new transaction object and purchasing the shipping label with one API call using shippo.transaction.create({...}). My user can request 1 or more of the same label at the same time. How can I include the number of labels they requested in the same PDF? I really don't want to do it in a batch since this is much quicker and straight-forward.

I have tried looping through

```
shippo.transaction.create(
        {
          shipment: shipment,
          carrier_account: carrierAccount.object_id,
          servicelevel_token: shipDetails.shippingMethod,
          label_file_type: 'PDF',
        })
```

but only ever get 1 back in return. This PDF will be either emailed or printed directly by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, we don't have an option to download/aggregate multiple labels into one PDF file via API/SDK.

Batch API can be used to group the purchased labels. This API will aggregate the label into one single PDF as well.

> Once your purchases are complete, you will be able to download a
> merged PDF file with the labels. Each PDF file will contain up to 100
> labels, the label_url field will contain an array of PDF files.

You can read about this further here: https://goshippo.com/docs/batch/

I am checking with my team as well. I will edit/add a comment if I find a workaround or an alternate solution.